# magento shopcart_product report

Tags: php, magento

I'm working in magento reports and I want to customize shopcart_product report, like:

Id
Product Name
Price
Orders
Carts Qty
Customer Name
Customer Type
Customer Id
IP

Please give me any idea for solve this problem.

```
<?php
class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Report_Shopcart_Product_Grid extends   Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Report_Grid_Shopcart
{

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->setId('gridProducts');
}

protected function _prepareCollection()
{

    /** @var $collection Mage_Reports_Model_Resource_Quote_Collection */
     $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/quote_collection');

    $filter = $this->getParam($this->getVarNameFilter(), array());
     if ($filter) {
         $filter = base64_decode($filter);
         parse_str(urldecode($filter), $data);
     }

     if (!empty($data)) {
         $collection->prepareForAbandonedReport($storeIds, $data);
     } else {
         $collection->prepareForAbandonedReport($storeIds);
     }


     $this->setCollection($collection);
     return parent::_prepareCollection();
   }

  /*  $collection->prepareForProductsInCarts()
         ->setSelectCountSqlType(Mage_Reports_Model_Resource_Quote_Collection::SELECT_COUNT_SQL_TYPE_CART);
}*/

protected function _prepareColumns()
{
    $this->addColumn('entity_id', array(
        'header'    =>Mage::helper('reports')->__('ID'),
        'width'     =>'50px',
        'align'     =>'right',
        'index'     =>'entity_id'
    ));


    $this->addColumn('name', array(
        'header'    =>Mage::helper('reports')->__('Product Name'),
        'index'     =>'name'
    ));

    $currencyCode = $this->getCurrentCurrencyCode();

    $this->addColumn('grand_total', array(
        'header'    =>Mage::helper('reports')->__('Price'),
        'width'     =>'80px',
        'type'      =>'currency',
        'currency_code' => $currencyCode,
        'index'     =>'grand_total',
        'renderer'  =>'adminhtml/report_grid_column_renderer_currency',
        'rate'          => $this->getRate($currencyCode),
    ));

    $this->addColumn('items_qty', array(
         'header'    =>Mage::helper('reports')->__('Carts Qty'),
         'width'     =>'80px',
         'align'     =>'right',
         'index'     =>'items_qty',
         'sortable'  =>false,
         'type'      =>'number'
     ));

    $this->addColumn('items_count', array(
        'header'    =>Mage::helper('reports')->__('Orders'),
        'width'     =>'80px',
        'align'     =>'right',
        'index'     =>'items_count'
    ));

    $this->addColumn('customer_name', array(
        'header'    =>Mage::helper('reports')->__('Customer Name'),
        'width'     =>'80px',
        'align'     =>'right',
        'index'     =>'customer_name'
    ));

    $this->addColumn('cust_type', array(
        'header'    =>Mage::helper('reports')->__('Customer Type'),
        'width'     =>'80px',
        'align'     =>'right',
        'index'     =>'customer_type'
    ));

    $this->addColumn('customer_id', array(
        'header'    =>Mage::helper('reports')->__('Customer Id'),
        'width'     =>'80px',
        'align'     =>'right',
        'index'     =>'customer_id'
    ));

    $this->addColumn('remote_ip', array(
        'header'    =>Mage::helper('reports')->__('IP'),
        'width'     =>'80px',
        'align'     =>'right',
        'index'     =>'remote_ip'
    ));

    $this->setFilterVisibility(false);

    $this->addExportType('*/*/exportProductCsv',  Mage::helper('reports')->__('CSV'));
    $this->addExportType('*/*/exportProductExcel', Mage::helper('reports')->__('Excel XML'));

    return parent::_prepareColumns();
  }

  public function getRowUrl($row)
   {
    return $this->getUrl('*/catalog_product_collection',  array('id'=>$row->getEntityId()));
    return $this->getUrl('*/customer/edit',  array('id'=>$row->getCustomerId(), 'active_tab'=>'cart'));
  }
   }
```